# Vim colorscheme not loading

Tags: vim

My vim colorscheme does not work properly when I set it in my .vimrc yet if I load it inside of vim it will work. My .vimrc:

```
 syntax on

 colorscheme jellybeans
 set t_Co=256
 set background=dark
```

By default, the scheme loads with the colors of the terminal. Loading it from inside vim using

```
 :colorscheme jellybeans
```

overrides this.

**Attempts to solve this**

- I do not have a .gvimrc so that's not the problem.
- The color is in my ~.vim/colors (proof is it works if I load it from inside vim)

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your `.vimrc` and the command you use to load it manually.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question now.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check which vimrc is loaded doing: `:echo $MYVIMRC`

Comment: I got '/Users/me/.vimrc' from the prompt

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this line](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/blob/master/colors/jellybeans.vim#L60) in the color scheme:

```
if has("gui_running") || &t_Co == 88 || &t_Co == 256
  let s:low_color = 0
else
  let s:low_color = 1
endif
```

If `t_Co` is too low, it uses different colors.

Try setting `t_Co` *before* loading the color scheme.

Comment: I'm running Terminal VIM from OSx