# Vim syntax theme; different behavior from .vimrc/colo call

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'd like to load a [vim syntax theme](https://github.com/fcevado/molokai_dark) from .vimrc.

The strange thing is that the theme looks different when loaded from .vimrc as it does when called from within vim with `colo molokai_dark`.

The `.vim` file doesn't have `if has("gui_running")` or `t_Co` (only in the 256 color terminal support-section) like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329115/vim-colorscheme-not-loading).

Why is that the case and how can I control this behavior?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention / show the actual changes, nor your actual configuration, and the colorscheme itself looks good, so I can only offer a workaround:

You can emulate the "from within Vim" via the following autocmd in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * colorscheme molokai_dark
```

Comment: thanks for your help, the workaround worked fine!

But to simply call this or any other scheme from within .vimrc with `colorscheme molokai_dark` still doesn't work...